# Selenium fails to change dropdown selection

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

Here is the isolated HTML code:

```
<span style="position: relative; width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
    <select id="0ac88542d16d6200fb983d094f655c76_select" class="form-control">
        <option value="display_value">Number</option>
        <option value="sys_class_name">Type</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

Using Python Selenium, click on the dropdown element to expand it:

```
search_elemets = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='form-control']")
search_elemets[0].click()
```

Now let's try different scenarios to change its selection to the desired value..

Option 1

```
Select(search_elemets[0]) \
    .select_by_visible_text("Number")
driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')[1].click()
```

Option 2

```
Select(search_elemets[0]) \
    .select_by_value("display_value")
driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')[1].send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Option 3

```
for option in search_elemets[0].find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if option.text == 'Number':

        # Use one of the options below
        # Option 3.1
        Select(search_elemets[0]) \
            .select_by_visible_text("Number")
        option.click()
        break

        # Option 3.2
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(option)
        actions.click(option)
        actions.perform()
        break
```

All tries result in a visual click which is performed by the webdriver, but
the value is not changed afterwards..

Comment: I think the search_elemets[0].click() line is not required...

Comment: Does the page work correctly with sanity manual testing?  Don't assume the problem is the Automated Test code.  Your locators are pretty iffy, use ID or Names are much preferable to produce robust locators.  Google "Selenium WebDriver locator strategy".  This FF plugin https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/element-locator-for-webdriv/ gives pretty good examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@katericata Your html is as like- Number Type Type2 Type3

and my web driver class is as, here you can replace the drop down items as Type2,type 3 etc which you want to select.

driver.findElement(By.xpath("code']")).sendKeys("Type3"); } } let me know if there are any concern.

Comment: Thanks. Using this line has worked: `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='form-control']").send_keys("N")`. As you can see, we are sending only the first character. If we send the entire text it does not, which is strange. We can run into trouble if we face dropdown with two entries starting with the same character.

Answer (score 0):

Class `form-control` might give you other elements. Try to locate by partial id

```
search_elemet = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[id*="select"]')
Select(search_elemet).select_by_visible_text('Number')
# or
Select(search_elemet).select_by_value('display_value')
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to use support UI's Select option. e.g.:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

select_element = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("0ac88542d16d6200fb983d094f655c76_select"))
print [o.text for o in select_element.options] # these are string-s
select_element.select_by_visible_text("Type")
# or 
select_element.select_by_value("display_value")
# or 
select_element.select_by_index(1)
```

Documentation [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html) and credit to Daniel Abel [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/what-is-the-correct-way-to-select-an-option-using-seleniums-python-webdriver).

Answer (score 0):

```
Use javascript executor :   
javascript executor helps to click small and hidden elements.
 element: the xpath to be executed. 

    public void javascriptclick(String element)
    { 
        WebElement webElement=driver.findElement(By.xpath(element));
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

        js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",webElement);   
        System.out.println("javascriptclick"+" "+ element);
    }
```

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.

Comment: javascript executor helps to click small and hidden elements.

element: the xpath to be executed.

Comment: The explanation should be in the post. There is an edit button above and to the left of this comment.